# Как избежать дублирования кода при перегрузке оператора

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, дублирование

Я перегружаю оператор :

```
void operator +=(pair<string, string> eng_rus) {
        root = insert(eng_rus.first, eng_rus.second, root);
    }
```

Но при этом мне так же надо перегрузить оператор ещё таким образом :

```
void operator +=(pair<char, string> eng_rus) {
    string s;
    s += eng_rus.first;
    root = insert(s, eng_rus.second, root);
}
```

И тд. Каким образом я могу избежать дублирования кода, возможно ли это в данной ситуации?

Comment: странный код честно говоря, зачем второй оператор? он же делает тоже самое, только с символом (что можно вполне интерпретировать как строку). Но даже если и есть на это какая-то гипотетическая причина, то можно в одну отдельную функцию просто перенести.

Comment: += на неинициализированной переменной мне кажется проблемой;)

Comment: это об `s+=...` ?

Comment: Если конструктор вызван, значит инициализирована.

Comment: переиспользовать оператор для `pair<string, string>`? `this += { string { eng_rus.first }, eng_rus.second };`

Comment: Мне необходимо перегрузить оператор, чтобы он мог принимать строки типа char*, т.е с парами <char,string>,<string,char>,<char,char>.

Comment: @s1rGAY все эти пары можно заменить одним лишь <string, string>

Comment: @ampawd Да, вы правы. Дело в том ,что у меня почему-то выдавало ошибку, когда я закидывал пару char в оператор, но теперь переписав понял, что string может работать с char без моих преобразований)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как в комментариях вы согласились с моим предложением, отвечу, что достаточно одного оператора:

```
void operator +=(pair<string, string> eng_rus) {
    root = insert(eng_rus.first, eng_rus.second, root);
}
```

Который может корректно принимать все указанные вами типы входных данных:
`<char,string>,<string,char>,<char,char>`

Тоесть символьный тип `char` абсолютно спокойно можно интерпретировать как строку `std::string`, который может инициализироваться одним символом.

Таким образом убирается дублирование операторов принимающих все эти типы.

**edit**
пример вызова

```
struct S
{
    void operator += (const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& eng_rus) {
        std::string s;
        s += eng_rus.first;
        //root = insert(s, eng_rus.second, root);
    }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s += std::pair<std::string, std::string>(std::string(1, '1'), std::string(1, '2'));    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно пример вызова этого оператора с `char`-ом?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat добавил пример

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу здесь дублирования кода. Если вся начинка вынесена в функцию `insert`, вы уже избавились от дублирования.

---

Вторую функцию можно немного сократить:

```
root = insert(std::string(1, eng_rus.first), eng_rus.second, root);
```

Comment: Мне необходимо чтобы оператор += работал как с парами <string,string>, так и с парами <char,string>,<string,char>,<char,char>. А в аргументы ф-ии у меня сейчас может поступать только пара str,str ,а для добавления условий с char получается такой же оператор за исключением пары моментов => не прям полное, но всё же существенное дублирование кода.